# How can I tell Puppet "If I declare class X, apply its resources before class Y"?

Tags: yum, puppet

In my Puppet configuration I want to say "If I declare class X, apply its resources before class Y." In other words, I want to declare an ordering, but remain silent about whether or not to apply class X.

If I understand the "before" metaparameter correctly, saying:

```
class X {
    ...
    before => Class['Y'],
}

class Y {
    ...
}

node N {
    include Y
}

node M {
    include X
    include Y
}
```

will include X's and Y's resources on both nodes M and N. Instead, what I want is to express separately, "Apply just Y," or "Apply X and Y, and apply X before Y."

For context, what I want to do more concretely is to ensure that my Yum repositories are configured before Puppet applies package resources. I want to omit some repositories from some nodes. I want my package resource definitions to remain naive about the corresponding repositories; I don't want to litter my package resource definitions with dependencies on specific repositories.

I tried using Run Stages, but beyond the simplest configuration, they seem to cause dependency cycles. For example, this would work:

```
stage { 'first': before => Stage['main'] }

class X {
    ...
    before => Class['Y'],
}

class Y {
    ...
}

node N {
    include Y
}

node M {
    class { "X": stage => first }
    include Y
}
```

But this wouldn't:

```
stage { 'first': before => Stage['main'] }

class X {
    ...
    class { "Z": stage => first } # to avoid Z "floating off"
    before => Class['Y'],
}

class Y {
    ...
    include Z
}

class Z { ... }

node N {
    include Y
}

node M {
    class { "X": stage => first }
    include Y
}
```

In the latter, Puppet thinks there is a dependency cycle. I presume that's due to Z being declared and its resources being managed in two different stages. I could potentially simplify the classes I need in stage "first" to avoid the dependency cycle problems I'm seeing in practice, but the Puppet documentation spreads [FUD](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/2.7/reference/lang_run_stages.html#limitations-and-known-issues) about Run Stages.

Here's the specific bit of configuration that makes Run Stages really unappealing to me. In development VMs I'm bootstrapping a Yum server locally via a "devrepo".

```
class yum::devrepo {

    # Ensures httpd is running as a Yum server before anything else
    # tries to install packages from it.
    exec { 'httpd-for-yum':
        command => '/sbin/service httpd restart',
        require => Class['yum::server'],
    }

    yumrepo {
        "devrepo":
            require    => [Exec['httpd-for-yum'],],
            descr      => "Local Dev YUM Repo",
            baseurl    => "http://localhost/repos/redhat/5/x86_64/",
            gpgcheck   => "0",
            enabled    => "1",
    }
}

class yum::server {

    include httpd

    package { ['createrepo']:
        ensure => present;
    }

    exec { 'update-repo-metadata':
        require => [ Package['createrepo']],
        cwd => '/var/www/html/yum',
        command => '/usr/bin/createrepo --update -d repos/redhat/5/x86_64/',
        creates => '/var/www/html/yum/repos/redhat/5/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml',
    }

    file {'/etc/httpd/conf.d/yum.conf':
        ensure  => file,
        mode    => 0644,
        source  => "puppet:///modules/yum/yum_httpd.conf",
        require => Package['httpd'],
        notify  => Service['httpd'],
    }
}
```

I want to include my production Yum repo on some nodes and the dev repo on others.

If I put `yum::server` and `yum::devrepo` in stage "first", then later httpd declarations in other classes cause problems later, because the other classes put httpd in the main stage.

If Puppet can express "If I declare class X, apply its resources before class Y", how? If not, how can I get the ordering I want without dependency cycles and without including Yum repository resources that I want to omit?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if it will work, but maybe you could try to define the dependencies on a node level scope. For example:

```
class X {
    ...
}

class Y {
    ...
}

node N {
   include Y
}

node M {
    Class['X'] -> Class['Y']
    include X
    include Y
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm trying something similar. Making progress. I'll share the details if it works.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like [golja's answer](https://serverfault.com/a/430230/64835) might work. Here's the pattern I landed on myself. It seems to be working so far.

```
class yum::reposareready {

    # The sole and critical purpose of this class is to act as an
    # intermediary between various repositories and the package
    # resources. It lets us do things like:

    # class yum::repofoo { ... }

    # class applicationbar {
    #     package { 'bazfromtherightrepo': ..., require => yum::reposareready, }
    # }

    # node n {
    #     class { 'yum::repofoo': before => Class['yum::reposareready'] }
    # }

    # With this pattern:

    # 1. The repository resource doesn't need to know about its ordering.

    # 2. Nodes can mix in repository resources, including and excluding
    #    repositories as needed.

    # 3. Classes that declare package resources need only require a
    #    generic "repos are ready" class rather than the knowing the
    #    specific repository from which to get a package.

    # DO NOT DO THIS:

    # class yum::repofoo { before => Class['yum::reposareready'] }
    # class yum::repobar { before => Class['yum::reposareready'] }
    #
    # node n {
    #     include yum::repofoo
    # }
    #
    # node m {
    #     include yum::repobar
    # }

    # The former scopes the ordering dependency to the node, whereas the
    # latter does not. The latter would make Puppet apply yum::repofoo
    # to both nodes n and m, whereas the former only applies
    # yum::repofoo to node n.

}
```